# How to store or any way to connect to mysql database with java

Tags: java, security

I have have a BIG problem in the past few days. I'm developing an application for a customer and I have an external database in the web. In the program there are a login and some modules. At the time I store the data for access to the DB hardcoded in the Java code. Of course this is not a way to store those data.
Then I was searching so much to find out a way to connect to the database.

- Store the password in a properties (.xml) file on the PC
- Encrypt the password
- etc.

But all of this is not really secure. Then I found something good. "Three-Tier Application Server" sounds really good and a possible way that I don't have to save the data on the PC. But I read everytime how a Three-Tier server works, but nowhere how to develop something like this in java. And is there a possibility that a hacker write an application that connects to this server too and get all of the data, because he decompile the application and get the access data?

Thanks for help

Comment: How to keep a server secure: keep the os and software (web host, ssh, ftp, etc) up to date, use ssh keys, make root inaccessible by ssh, have root password be 15 random characters (there are ~97 on the keyboard), change the ssh port (for some reason this has stopped a significant number of ddos ssh attacks against me, case in point, if you write a botnet, have it automatically use nmap).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are indeed many ways you can go about this. 
The best way is to have the authentication checks spread throughout your code to where it would be very hard to remove them.

Have the authentication with SHA256/512 and or MD5 and have the user send a login request to the server. 
Only authenticate the user if the server responds that it is registered.

Do not store any information other than the users info on the client end. 
All the checks should be made and validated on the server side.

You also most definitely want to obfuscate your client sided code as well.

Comment: How the client should be validate? Send a random UUID with the userlogin informations?